# How can I go back to a search result table that is in a partial view?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I'm working in a ASP.NET MVC project that accesses an SQL database and allows the user to search and view the data. Let me describe it:
I have a view with a search filter. When I click in a search button in this view, the controller returns a partial view with a table with some data, which appears below the filter. Then, I can click in an actionLink of a row to go to another view with the details. In the Details view I have a "back to list" button.
When I click in "back to list", I want the view, that has the filter and the partial view, to appear exactly as it was before. How can I do this?

My "back to list" is an actionlink that goes to the view. The problem is that, when I click in "back to list", the partial view  with the table doesn't appear because it is necessary to click in the submit button first. How could I force the submit button through the controller?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a problem that is solved inherently with MVC. It's really just a state concern, where you need to persist the state of a page, and resume that state when coming back to it.

This can be solved through typical means of persisting state between pages:

1) Save your search criteria in the session, and retrieve them when returning to the page.

2) Pass your search criteria through the link to the details page, and then again on the "back to list" link.

And (as the comment below points out), you'll of course need to then use the values from the session/querystring to run the search again and render the search results to the view, just as you did when you originally performed the search.

Comment: And you'll also need to run the code that loads the partial view when the search page loads.  I'm guessing you you a javascript/jquery click handler for the button?  Restore the form values via the session values as suggested here and then run the same code that the button click runs after the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is open the link content in another tab... using `<a href="..." target="_blank">Clic here</a>`

**Client side option:**
You could load the content of the link in another container `<div>`... hiding the one that holds the search results and filters. Then, when user clics "Back to search...", you just show the container with the search results and filters, and hide and clean the other container.

This code is not so hard, and you don't need to go to the server again.

If you are OK with reloading the page, **@Jerard Rose, in his answer**, explains 2 other approachs that involves re-loading the search results, querying again the database.

Comment: Easiest doesn't always mean the best UX. And developers need to (in most cases) be more concerned about what is best for the users vs. what is best for the developer. Unless the developer is the user, in which case, do whatever floats your boat.

Comment: True... but indid there is an easy way... and should be the person that asked who choose the best one for his scenary and level of expertise. ;)

Comment: Agreed, that's why I didn't down-vote your answer. ;) This is perfectly acceptable, if your users are ok with the UX this yields. I personally don't prefer a UX that involves opening a new window (except maybe for some edge cases), which is why I personally wouldn't advise this as an option.

Answer (score 0):

Values can be transferred between pages in many ways such as: Session, QueryString, Public property, Cookie, HTTPContext.

Perhaps you are calling a 'details' action to travel to the details page. What can you do is that,

```
1. When you go to the details page, store your search filter value and pass it to the details page. so that when you return to the previous page you can get back/pass the values again if needed.
2. Now if you click 'back to list' button pass the values that you already have for filtering to your desired action which is responsible for the partial view.
3. Do the same thing that you did while clicking on the 'Search' button in the action.
```

Hope this will help
Thanks